# Using OnEditorActionListener on an EditText that has specified digits

Tags: java, android

I have an EditText that only accepts lowercase alphabetical characters, which I accomplish using `digits` .

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/play_edit_enter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:maxLength="1"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    />
```

There is also a button next to it that performs an action. I would like however to also be able to use the "Enter" key (for lack of a better name) on the keyboard to call that button.

```
    progressEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                progressButton.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This works fine if I get rid of the `android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"` line. But I want to use that line.  Perhaps the reason it doesn't work is because the Enter key is not included in those digits?

**Q:** If that is the case, what would I need to add? Or otherwise, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This works fine if I get rid of the android:digits="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm" line. But I want to use that line.

You should remove that line, because it does not do what you think it does. It actually specifies that the EditText will only accept digits, and only the digits you specify in the value, which in your case is `"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"`, which obviously has no digits.

Also see [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:digits)

> **android:digits**
>
> If set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method and that these specific characters are the ones that it will accept. If this is set, numeric is implied to be true. The default is false.

I know it says TextView, but EditText inherits that attribute from TextView.

What you can do is check `@android:inputType` and see if there is anything that it can do for you.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType